# Can I install Ubuntu 13.10 without the internet?

Tags: installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

I'm currently out of town and the dorm I am living in has terrible internet connection. It won't be another 2-3 weeks before I can go home and have proper internet connection.

So my question is whether or not I can install Ubuntu 13.10 in my laptop without the internet and then do the updates once I go home?

Also, I'm attempting to do a dual boot with my Lenovo G505s which was pre-installed with Windows 8. Hopefully I can pull this off.

I already did the necessary things (I think and hope so) prior to installation:

1. Disable secure boot
2. Enable legacy and boot UEFI first
3. Create partition
4. Put installer in my pen drive

As I am quite new to this, any advice would be of great help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried yesterday. The installation asked me to connect to the internet, so I used my crappy dorm internet. When it reached the downloading/installtion of Ubuntu One, it just stopped and went on forever. So I had to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is whether or not I can install Ubuntu 13.10 in my laptop without the internet and then do the updates once I go home?

Yes. I myself always never set up my wireless during installation.

> Also, I'm attempting to do a dual boot with my Lenovo G505s which was pre-installed with Windows 8. Hopefully I can pull this off.

If others can so can you.

---

Just a remark: sometimes it is helpful to have a connection at hand just for a quick check on how to handle something unexpected. But that does not need to be the system you install Ubuntu on.

Comment: Thanks! I read online (I forgot link) that there are updates that are hardware specific? If so, I can access these later on, right?

Comment: yes you can do that after install

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use a CD or a bootable flash disc, but you might need updates latter.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need an internet connection for is the installation of third-party software, especially the mp3 plugin from the Frauenhoffer Institut, if I remember correctly.

At the moment the instant update isn't very crucial because Ubuntu 13.10 released a short time ago. So there aren't many updates out there yet. And my experience was that Ubuntu 13.10 worked very well without doing an instant update after installing.

So do your installation if you want to use Ubuntu right now :)